# Why does this dart program hang for 5 seconds after the last line of main()?

Tags: dart

When I run this code, it outputs `starting...`, the HTTP repsonse body and then `finished` but then seems to wait for approx 5 seconds before the Dart process terminates.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

Future<String> _sendRequest() async {
  var http = new HttpClient();
  return http
      .postUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/404"))
      .then((HttpClientRequest request) => request.close())
      .then((HttpClientResponse response) {
    return response.transform(UTF8.decoder).join("");
  });
}

main(List<String> args) async {
  print("starting...");
  print(await _sendRequest());
  print("finished");
}
```

Why? What's happening after the last `print()` that takes so long to end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HttpClient` also needs closing:

```
Future<String> _sendRequest() async {
  var http = new HttpClient();
  return http
      .postUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/404"))
      .then((HttpClientRequest request) => request.close())
      .then((HttpClientResponse response) {
    return response.transform(UTF8.decoder).join("");
  }).whenComplete(() => http.close()); // <-- ####################
}
```

Comment: I know this question is forever old, but helped me track down the same issue. @Danny or anyone else who knows, is there a way I could have discovered the un-closed object using Observatory instead of having to sift through my code for possibilities?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest - I can't even remember how I tracked this down. It's something I've been aware of since though!